# How to write the next line in a text file to a new text file

Tags: python, xml, text-files

I'm trying to sort data in a text-file by using XML tags. I know about all the libraries but that's not the way I want to go about doing it. If the file I have is:

```
UIHC
2
A31415
54
M
180
98
6.7
100
No
130
65
A32545
62
F
160
80
7.2
120
Yes
180
92
```

I need the output to look like:

```
<patient>       
<patientID>A31415</patientID>   
<age>54</age>   
<gender>M</gender>  
<height>180</height>    
<weight>90</weight> 
<hba1c>6.7</hba1c>  
<cholesterol>100</cholesterol>  
<smoker>No<smoker>  
<systolic>130</systolic>    
<diastolic>65</diastolic>   
</patient>  
<patient>       
<patientID>A32545</patientID>       
<age>62</age>   
<gender>F</gender>  
<height>160</height>    
<weight>80</weight> 
<hba1c>7.2</hba1c>  
<cholesterol>120</cholesterol>  
<smoker>Yes<smoker> 
<systolic>180</systolic>    
<diastolic> 92</diastolic>  
</patient>
```

My code is:

```
def codeData(filename):
    newFile = filename
    newFile = newFile.replace(".txt", "")
    newFile = str(newFile) + "XML.txt"    
    originalFile = open(filename,'r')    
    firstLine  = originalFile.readline()
    secondLine = originalFile.readline()
    original = originalFile.readlines()
    index = 0
    file = open(newFile, 'w')
    for line in original:
        index = index + 1
        if index%11 == 1:
            file.write('<patientID>'+str(original[0]).strip('\n')+'</patientID>\n')
        if index%11 == 2:
            file.write('<age>'+str(original[1]).strip('\n')+'</age>\n')
        if index%11 == 3:
            file.write('<gender>'+str(original[2]).strip('\n')+'</gender>\n')
        if index%11 == 4:
            file.write('<height>'+str(original[3]).strip('\n')+'</height>\n')
        if index%11 == 5:
            file.write('<weight>'+str(original[4]).strip('\n')+'</weight>\n')
        if index%11 == 6:
            file.write('<HBA1C>'+str(original[5]).strip('\n')+'</HBA1C>\n')
        if index%11 == 7:
            file.write('<cholesterol>'+str(original[6]).strip('\n')+'</cholesterol>\n')
        if index%11 == 8:
            file.write('<smoker>'+str(original[7]).strip('\n')+'</smoker>\n')
        if index%11 == 9:
            file.write('<systolic>'+str(original[8]).strip('\n')+'</systolic>\n')
        if index%11 == 10:
            file.write('<diastolic>'+str(original[9]).strip('\n')+'</diastolic>\n')
```

But with this code my output repeats only one of the patients. I know it's because I'm specifying to write a specific line. My output is:

```
<patientID>A31415</patientID>
<age>54</age>
<gender>M</gender>
<height>180</height>
<weight>98</weight>
<HBA1C>6.7</HBA1C>
<cholesterol>100</cholesterol>
<smoker>No</smoker>
<systolic>130</systolic>
<diastolic>65</diastolic>
<patientID>A31415</patientID>
<age>54</age>
<gender>M</gender>
<height>180</height>
<weight>98</weight>
<HBA1C>6.7</HBA1C>
<cholesterol>100</cholesterol>
<smoker>No</smoker>
<systolic>130</systolic>
```

So my question is how do I write the next line in the file, instead of repeating.
Any help would be appreciated. And yes, all the information is completely made up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `for index, line in enumerate(original)` to iterate over your input without having to keep track of the index yourself.
2. Access the current `line` the for-loop gives you instead of using (and especially hardcoding) indices like `original[0]`.
3. Once everything works like you want it to, you might want to consider using a list or dictionary of XML tags instead of the long list of `if`s you're using now.

Comment: thank you, but now one more question, how come it ends with systolic when diastolic should be the last one?

Comment: Your datasets are 10 lines each, so you'll have to use `% 10` instead of `% 11` (assuming you're using a zero-based index) and compare the result to the values 0 to 9 (instead of 1 to 10).